# Feed Neural Network with Data (encog library)

Tags: java

I am building an an agent based model for an artificial stock market. A part of the model is that the agents will use the historical returns of the stock and passe it to the neural network in order to predict the future return. I am using encog library to do so. However, the historical returns are generated artificially by the the model so that there is no actual data or CSV file to read from. The returns are sorted in array-list. How to pass these return to the input as the XOR example

```
public class XOR {

public static double XOR_INPUT[][] = { { 0.0, 0.0}, { 1.0, 0.0},
{ 0.0, 1.0}, { 1.0, 1.0 } };

public static double XOR_IDEAL[][] = { { 0.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 0.0 } };

}
```

my previous returns for the past for past 7 days are :

1   -0.003
2   -0.003
3   -0.002
4   0.001
5   -0.003
6   -0.001
7   -1.023E-4

so if the agents using 3 days lagger returns the inputs and ideal should be like this:

```
public class XOR {

public static double XOR_INPUT[][] = { { -0.003, -0.003,-0.002}, { -0.003,   -0.002,0.001},{-0.002, 0.001,-0.003}, {0.001,-0.003,-0.001} };

public static double XOR_IDEAL[][] = { { 0.001 }, { -0.003 }, { -0.001 }, { -1.023E-4}  };

}
```

any idea how can I pass these values to the neural network to activate the following code with the required data described above:

```
// create the neural net work
final FeedforwardNetwork network = new FeedforwardNetwork();
network.addLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(3)); // nodes in the input layer
network.addLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(3)); // nodes in the hidden layer
network.addLayer(new FeedforwardLayer(1)); // nodes in the output layer
network.reset();

// train the neural network
final Train train = new Backpropagation(network, XOR.XOR_INPUT, XOR.XOR_IDEAL,0.7,  0.9);

int epoch = 1;

do {
train.iteration();
System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + " Error:" + train.getError());
epoch++;
} while ((epoch < 5000) && (train.getError() > 0.001));

// test the neural network
System.out.println("Neural Network Results:");
for (int i = 0; i < XOR.XOR_IDEAL.length; i++) {
final double actual[] = network.computeOutputs( XOR.XOR_INPUT[i]);
System.out.println( XOR.XOR_INPUT[i][0] + "," + XOR.XOR_INPUT[i][1]+ ", actual=" +     actual[0] + ",ideal=" + XOR.XOR_IDEAL[i][0]);
}
```

Many Thanks